# jQuery ajax success callback not firing

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

I'm using jQuery's `$.ajax` method to fetch data from a JSONP-compatible web service and as far as getting a response and displaying the received data in my HTML, everything seems to be working fine. However, I haven't been able to get the ajax method's success callback to fire. What's even stranger is that even when I do get a valid response from the service, the error callback is always fired.

Here is an example of a simple js function I made to test this:

```
function doJsonp()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://example.com/api/service?callback=blah",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function() { console.log("success"); }, // This is never fired
        error: function() { console.log("error"); } // This is always fired
    });
}
```

and the matching callback function:

```
function blah(data)
{
    console.log(data); // This is called properly
}
```

From reading similar questions here on SO and elsewhere, it seems that this is most often caused by the service returning JSON that does not validate. For my purposes, I am using an in-house web service but have tried other JSONP services as well, such as those provided by Flickr, for example:

http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_pool.gne?id=807213@N20&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=blah

Both the JSON from Flickr's service and mine validate using jsonlint so that does not seem to be the issue as far as I can tell.

In searching for solutions to this problem, I have tried using a jQuery plugin called jquery-jsonp, found at http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/. This replaces jQuery's `$.ajax` call with its own `$.jsonp` so the above code looks like this:

```
function doJsonp()
{
    $.jsonp({
        url: "http://example.com/api/service?callback=blah",
        success: function() { console.log("success"); },
        error: function() { console.log("error"); }
    });
}
```

However, the result is the same and the success callback never fires. Any help or a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the server response ? You can find it in develeopers tools such as Dragonfly(opera), Firebug(FireFox), Developer Tools (Chrome)

Comment: url: "http://example.com/api/service?callback=blah" != your function name bleh(). Might that be a typo?

Comment: @BartoszGrzybowski The server response status is a 200 OK

Comment: @junior That was a typo I made while typing up the question, I've fixed it now.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss My apologies, I will remember that next time. Though the issue wasn't so much with the handling of the error, but rather that it was being thrown when it shouldn't have been.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

define the callback-function via the **`jsonpCallback`**-option, not inside the url:

```
function doJsonp()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_pool.gne?id=807213@N20&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonpCallback:'blah',//<<<
        success: function() { console.log("success"); }, 
        error: function() { console.log("error"); } 
    });
}
```